# How do i turn multiple java files into a single executable file?

Tags: java, executable

I have a  program that i wrote with 3 java files but it uses images and text files in other folders, is there any way to put it all in any jar file or exe or something similar? Im using dr java. this is what it looks like now [screeenshot](http://puu.sh/7VhLQ/8241095955.jpg)

Comment: There are many tools [available to do this job](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=convert+java+to+exe&oq=convert+java+to+exe&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3098j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8). StackOverflow is not the right place to ask this question as any answers will be opinion-based.

Comment: @Vish where did he ask for a ".exe" ?? Kevin anyway get a propper IDE, netbeans, eclipse, intelliJ... the one you want. For a beginner i'd advise netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile them to classes and them join them to one (executable) JAR file as described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Edit: [Eclipse](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-jee-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz) has a feature to export (right click on project/Export.../JAR) to a jar file right away.

Comment: Thanks, but where do i type jar cf jar-file input-file(s)? And when i complie them this happens [screen](http://puu.sh/7VifF/7e3598f3a3.png)

Comment: Click the Start button Picture of the Start button. In the Search box, type Command Prompt, and then, in the list of results, double-click Command Prompt. In command prompt you need to get to the directory your files are located - you can do that by typing "cd YOUR_DIRECTORY" without quotes where your directory is a full path to your directory to get to your directory. Then you can type it there. How did you get them compiled in the first place?

Comment: I used a compiler in Dr.Java.

Comment: You might want to checkout Eclipse editor which have an ability to just export your project as a JAR file. Alternatively you can do it in command line as I described, but you need to make sure you specify full path to the jar executable.